# Deploying a website like Instagram, what is required?

Tags: mysql, django, apache, web-applications, deployment

I am working on a team which is making a website similar to, say, Instagram. Similar in the sense that we are employing similar technologies in the back end, but the concept has no relation to Instagram.

Anyway, I was reading this article here which describes Instagram's compete stack:

[What Powers Instagram: Hundreds of Instances, Dozens of Technologies](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/13649370142/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances-dozens-of)

I'll be honest - I was quite overwhelmed by the number of different technologies they employ. What I want to know is that is it necessary to start with so many different and specific technologies to make something which can sustain a lot of traffic, and continue to work just fine?

Currently, we are working with an Apache web server, MySQL database, Django/python framework, HTML/CSS/Javascript front end, and Ajax to make things more dynamic - you know, the works. We are aiming to utilize Amazon Web Services to host our project. Our project is being built on Linux machines (Ubuntu).

Do we need to use a lot of other software packages/tools to ensure our website is top-notch? It is fully functional from our perspective. This may seem like a novice question, but we are novices relative to Instagram developers.

Comment: If it works, it works. I would recommend using Fabric to deploy your project and Gunicorn as a server (you could also use uWSGI, Tornado, etc.), but the other stuff is just there to support the enormous amount of traffic that the site gets. You might end up utilizing those technologies later on, but if you don't see a need to add the features, don't add them.

Comment: This question is overwhelming

Answer (score 3):

Start simple. Specialize as you have need.

Instagram is a MASSIVE property, and serves a lot of traffic under uncommon circumstances. Don't take their infrastructure as the way to start things. Start with what works, and then as you find things don't work, replace them.

As web projects grow and mature over time, they will often incorporate more and more specialized technologies and architectures to accommodate their specific needs. Don't take their infrastructures as a template, but rather, as a lesson to expect to grow and evolve your infrastructure as your product evolves.

Measure everything. Know where you need to get better. Iterate. GOTO 1. :)